# Injection of autowired dependencies failed with Qualifier

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have tried all the options i could find anywhere, i looked at all questions previously asked on the topic and tried solutions given in those, but nothing worked, all i get is this error.

**Errors**

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'circle': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void spring.springdemo.Circle.setCenter(spring.springdemo.Point); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [spring.springdemo.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: pointA,pointB,pointC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at spring.springdemo.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void spring.springdemo.Circle.setCenter(spring.springdemo.Point); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [spring.springdemo.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: pointA,pointB,pointC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [spring.springdemo.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: pointA,pointB,pointC
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    ... 15 more
```

The files i created in this example are as below.

**spring.xml**
This is the schema defination

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

This is the place i wants to be apply autowired.

```
 <bean id="circle" class="spring.springdemo.Circle">

</bean>

<bean id="pointA" class="spring.springdemo.Point">
    <qualifier value="CircleRelated"/>
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    <property name="y" value="0"/>
</bean>
<bean id="pointB" class="spring.springdemo.Point">
        <property name="x" value="-20"/>
        <property name="y" value="0"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="pointC" class="spring.springdemo.Point">
        <property name="x" value="20"/>
        <property name="y" value="0"/>
    </bean>
```

These are the classes those, i have added.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**Circle.java**
The class, thats object will be populated by autowire

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;


public class Circle implements Shape{
    private Point center;

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
        System.out.println("Point is : ("+center.getX()+", "+center.getY()+")");
    }
    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CircleRelated")
    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have <context:annotation-config/> in your context.xml. Check spring reference chapter 5.9. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner
This lines
`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver"/>`
    `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>`
I added them and i shouldn't have needed `<context:annotation-config/>` but I had to can you please tell why?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner Why I need to provide all BeanPostProcessor by writing <context: annotation-config/> while i am already providing class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireC‌​andidateResolver"/>  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostP‌​rocessor"/> beans.  Please Explain it......

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to remove the `<qualifier value="CircleRelated"/>` from the xml and inject the dependency straight forward from the id. The id in the xml is enough in most of the cases, the qualifier can be used only for specific cases. And the convention is to use a lowercase for the first letter of the id or qualifier.

So, change `CircleRelated` of `@Qualifier("CircleRelated")` by an existing id like `@Qualifier("pointA")`, `@Qualifier("pointB")` or `@Qualifier("pointC")`

Comment: It wont matter, yes the Id's are very unique in it, but they are not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines of code and make sure to add context namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```